# How CMOS RAM stores year in one byte

Tags: assembly, system, masm, bios

In [this website](http://www.bioscentral.com/misc/cmosmap.htm), I find that the year in CMOS RAM is stored in just one byte.

[image]

It is known that one byte only holds 0 to 255, so I write this code to get what 09H store:

```
assume cs:code,ss:stack

stack segment
    db 64 dup (0)
stack ends

code segment
    start:
    mov ax,stack
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,64

    mov al,09H
    out 70H,al
    in al,71H

    mov ah,4CH
    int 21H
code ends

end start
```

I get a return value 17H from port 71H, so does it mean CMOS RAM stores year by `1994 + offset value`?

If so, what does number 1994 mean? In the future, how CMOS RAM stores the year more than 2249(1994+255)?

Comment: Data is encoded in BCD, not binary.  Something that (barely) made sense 32 years ago.  The high nibble contains the first decimal digit, the low nibble the 2nd digit.  Range is [0..99].  And yes, we do live in the year 2017 so what you got is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The register 09h of the [CMOS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/techspec/CMOS-reference.txt) stores the current year in the *current century*.
Its value ranges from 0 to 99.

> ```
> ----------R09--------------------------------  
> CMOS 09h - RTC - YEAR  
> Desc:   (BCD 00-99, Hex 00-63)  
> Notes:  BCD/Hex selection depends on Bit 2 of register B (0Bh)
> ```

It is encoded either as BCD (values 0x00 to 0x99) or as plain binary (values 0x00 to 0x63).
The encoding is determined by the bit2 of register 0xb

> ```
> ----------R0B--------------------------------  
> CMOS 0Bh - RTC - STATUS REGISTER B (read/write)  
>
> Bitfields for Real-Time Clock status register B:  
> Bit(s)  Description     (Table C002)  
>  7      enable cycle update  
>  6      enable periodic interrupt  
>  5      enable alarm interrupt  
>  4      enable update-ended interrupt  
>  3      enable square wave output  
>  2      Data Mode - 0: BCD, 1: Binary  
>  1      24/12 hour selection - 1 enables 24 hour mode  
>  0      Daylight Savings Enable - 1 enables
> ```

---

In my system register 0xb has value *0x2* (24-h enabled, BCD date).
Register 0x9 reads 0x17 for 2017, which is correct, in my frame of reference, for my timeline.

Comment: From the previous answer, I have another question. Why different operating systems (or different programming languages) have quite different epoch and range?

Comment: @Kon Because they were designed by different people. Back in the 80's saving a byte was worth it. Later we acknowledged the error and used an int (4 bytes on most architectures). Later this turned out problematic again and we doubled the size in modern libraries.

Comment: I mean the date have been stored in CMOS accurately and the operating system (including BIOS) read the current date from CMOS RAM. So their epoch and range should be same as CMOS RAM. But the fact is that everyone have their own epoch and range.

Comment: @Kon, the RTC is only used to keep track of time when the system is powered off. When the OS boots it applies a correction factor to the RTC time and estimate a time. The more accurate time is fetched from a time-keeping server through NTP. You can read [this interesting article about this issue](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Clock-2.html). The OS has always interpreted the RTC time, an older version of MS-DOS may think we are in the year 1917 while an earlier Windows may infer 2017 because the programmers applied a correction for the years before the OS release.

Answer (score 0):

Year calcolation depend of your Operating systems and [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) reference date!

Check also: [System time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_time)

Example:
**DOS (Microsoft)** have range from 1 January 1980 to 31 December 2099.

Year values bigger than 2099 are not supported!

Comment: Indeed. Do you mean date stored in CMOS is just **data**. How to understand it depends of Operating systems?